# Foreach returns only one output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

Okay so I am stuck here and I know there would be a simple solution, but I can't figure it out. So the thing is that I have a function which creates columns in a database if not exists. I got the function to work but I want to add the functionality in the function of detecting the column type (VARCHAR, INT etc) and creating columns accordingly. I am trying to get this done by `gettype` keyword. Now, `$productData` is in array so I need to apply foreach to get them separated and then I get the value type, the problem is that in the end foreach loop, it gives me only string. Where `$productData` has 4 strings and 1 integer ..

```
$array       = (array) $productData;
$arrayValues = array_values( $array );
$i = 0;

foreach ( $arrayValues as $key => $value ) {
    $types = array( "id-$i" => gettype( $value ) );
    $i++;
}
var_dump($types);
```

Can somebody help me out there please?

Thanks ..

Comment: a variable can only have one value...

Comment: I'm storing it in array. If you var_dump inside foreach it gives you all output correctly ..

Comment: no it won't. you incorrectly intrepret the output.

Comment: Yea, my bad. Got the correct one from fejese. Thanks anyways ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialise the array only once and add elements to it later:

```
$array       = (array) $productData;
$arrayValues = array_values( $array );
$i = 0;

$types = array();
foreach ($arrayValues as $key => $value) {
    $types["id-$i"] = gettype($value);
    $i++;
}
var_dump($types);
```

<strike>Be careful with `gettype()` as it will fail on bojects. You need to make sure that each `$value` is an internal type</strike>

**Update:**
The `gettype()` will return `"object"` for all objects. So it is a safe way to determine the type of a variable. Although in case you need the class of the object you need to use `get_class()` in case `gettype()` returns `"object"`

Comment: Thanks Fejese, that worked. I am not sure what you meant by internal type?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Fejese, I will use `gettype` for this one as its used for a variable. But I think I will be using `get_class` soon for my further work.

Comment: Though the code is correct, why is it so complicated? `$types = array_map('gettype', (array)$productData);` does pretty much the same.

Comment: @Yoshi, you're absolutely correct, I just thought that pointing out the mistake in OP's implementation helps him to better understand what was wrong with the code initially

Answer (score 1):

If you are selecting the table definitions first using the MYSQL command: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable` that will return an array of columns with their definitions

Comment: I dealt with MySQL in other place, I am just getting the type for every entry in product so that I could add new column for it.